# Do I need to create a different awk script if I don't want to perform the same actions on all of the files i pass as parameters?

Tags: bash, awk

I'm a noob writing an awk script to combine two differently formatted files and insert specific data from each into another file, and I was wondering how I could specify which actions to perform on which files? In constructing the pattern statement I want to reference a different field number depending on which file I'm dealing with. Would that require a separate script? Ex:

```
file 1:
blue 6'0
brown 5'8
green 5'4

file 2:
36 28 20
```

and then I'd like to combine these two into (after a specfic string)

```
file 3:
*string*
blue 6'0 36
brown 5'8 20
green 5'4 28
```

I know in bash scripting the $ references parameter number, but in awk that sign references field number. Any insight you could provide would be helpful. Thanks

Comment: Can you show us with an actual input and an _exact_ output you need out of it?

Comment: all `awk`s support the `FILENAME` variable. You can match against that and have a conditional logic based on that. Good luck.

Comment: Would that require me to know the filename?

Comment: The only thing puzzling about your question is `*string*`. Where did that appear from? Is it existing text in `file3` or text you are writing to file3, or do you need to write to the end of file3 or do you need to write into file3 between `*string*` and the line after it or something else? In other words - clarify what `*string*` is all about as it is the key to a working solution.

Comment: the string is existent in the file already, its where im going to insert this new text in file3

Comment: That, of course, is a crucially important detail. [edit] your question to show the before and after of file3 so we're not just answering 10% of your question.

Comment: string is just the text in file3 which I'd like to append to after. But its not at the end of the file

Comment: Yes I understand that now but it wasn't clear from your question because you didn't include a before/after for `file3` that showed `string` mid-file.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from whatever it is you need to do with `*string*`, all you need is:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{split($0,a);next} {print $0,a[FNR]}' file2 file1
blue 6'0 36
brown 5'8 28
green 5'4 20
```

Given your clarified requirement that the above output has to go after the text "string" in file3:

```
$ cat file3
foo
string
bar

$ awk '
    ARGIND==1 { split($0,a) }
    ARGIND==2 { new = new $0 OFS a[FNR] ORS }
    ARGIND==3 { print; if (/string/) printf "%s", new }
' file2 file1 file3
foo
string
blue 6'0 36
brown 5'8 28
green 5'4 20
bar
```

The above uses GNU awk for ARGIND, if you don't have GNU awk then just add a line `FNR==1{ARGIND++}` at the start of the script.

Comment: what is the a that appears a few times?

Comment: Its an array. I don't know what the contents of file2 represent so I couldn't come up with a meaningful name for it. To learn Awk, read the book Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins.

Answer (score 0):

Given:

```
$ cat f1
blue 6'0
brown 5'8
green 5'4

$ cat f2
36 28 20

$ cat f3 
line 1
string line 2
line 3
string line 4
line 5
```

You can use this `awk` with `paste`:

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR{s=s ? s ORS $0 : $0; next} 
       1; 
       /string/ {print s}' <(paste -d' ' f1 <(tr ' ' '\n' <f2)) f3
```

Prints:

```
line 1
string line 2
blue 6'0 36
brown 5'8 28
green 5'4 20
line 3
string line 4
blue 6'0 36
brown 5'8 28
green 5'4 20
line 5
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand the question, this should do:

```
xargs -n1 -a file2 | paste -d" " file1 -
```

You can prepend arbitrary strings in the usual way:

```
( echo "string" ; xargs -n1 -a file2 | paste -d" " file1 - ) > file3
```